# How to block mouse inputs and simulate them programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a task to make a software model of device which has touchpad and screen.

I'm using C# and Windows XP.

So I have TouchpadPanel and ScreenPanel. 
How can I route mouse inputs of TouchpadPanel to ScreenPanel? I want ScreenPanel (or ScreenForm) not to capture mouse and its events but to get them from TouchpadPanel. Is it really possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent couple of days trying to figure out the best way to solve the problem which I described above. 
Finally I found very good manner which helped me successfully finish requested job.
I decided to share with you - hopefully it might save you some time.

I used System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint to create all the controls that I needed from scratch: buttons, labels, custom textboxes and comboboxes. Most important of all - I made separate top layer for cursor.

Now when I'm drawing everything myself I can draw extra cursor which is always visible in my window no matter what I'm doing with the real cursor.

[image]
[image]

Here is some code example:

```
class MCDUComboBox : MCDUStateControl
{
    public event EventHandler<GosNIIAS.EventArgs<string>> SelectedIndexChanged;

    private const int buttonOffset = 2;
    private const int buttonWidth = 20;
    private const int buttonHeight = 20;

    private string[] m_items;
    private int m_hightlight_index;
    private int m_selected_index;
    private Rectangle m_drop_down_bounds;
    private int m_scroll_index;
    private ButtonState m_top_scroll_button_state;
    private ButtonState m_bottom_scroll_button_state;

    #region Properties

    public string[] Items
    {
        get { return m_items; }
        set { m_items = value; }
    }

    public override string Text
    {
        get { return base.Text; }
        set
        {
            if (ControlState == ControlState.Normal)
                base.Text = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public MCDUComboBox()
    {
        this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(204)));

        this.m_items = new string[0];
        this.m_hightlight_index = -1;
        this.m_selected_index = -1;
        this.m_drop_down_bounds = new Rectangle();
        this.m_scroll_index = 0;
        this.m_top_scroll_button_state = ButtonState.Normal;
        this.m_bottom_scroll_button_state = ButtonState.Normal;
    }

    public override void Draw(Graphics g)
    {
        if (Visible)
        {
            Rectangle bounds = ClipRectangle;

            if (ControlState == ControlState.Normal)
            {
                g.FillRectangle(BackBrush, bounds);
                g.DrawString(Text, Font, ForeBrush, bounds, StringFormat);
            }
            else if (ControlState == ControlState.Edit)
            {
                g.FillRectangle(ForeBrush, bounds);
                ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(g, bounds, Border3DStyle.Sunken);

                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(bounds.X + bounds.Width - buttonOffset - buttonWidth,
                                                    bounds.Y + buttonOffset,
                                                    buttonWidth,
                                                    bounds.Height - 2 * buttonOffset);
                ControlPaint.DrawComboButton(g, rectangle, ButtonState.Normal);
            }
            else if (ControlState == ControlState.WaitingFeedback)
            {
                g.FillRectangle(BackBrush, bounds);
                g.DrawString(Text, Font, WaitFeedbackBrush, bounds, StringFormat);
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Visible)
        {
            Rectangle bounds = ClipRectangle;

            if (bounds.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                {
                    if (ControlState == ControlState.Normal)
                        ControlState = ControlState.Edit;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (ControlState == ControlState.Edit)
                    ControlState = ControlState.Normal;
            }
        }
    }

    public override bool OnMouseDownTopLayer(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Visible && ControlState == MCDU.Drawing.ControlState.Edit)
        {
            if (m_drop_down_bounds.Contains(e.Location) && m_items.Length > 0)
            {
                Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(m_drop_down_bounds.X,
                                                 m_drop_down_bounds.Y,
                                                 m_items.Length > 10 ? m_drop_down_bounds.Width - buttonWidth 
                                                                     : m_drop_down_bounds.Width,
                                                 m_drop_down_bounds.Height);
                if (bounds.Contains(e.Location))
                {
                    if (SelectedIndexChanged != null)
                    {
                        int itemHeight = m_drop_down_bounds.Height / Math.Min(10, m_items.Length);
                        m_selected_index = (e.Location.Y - m_drop_down_bounds.Y) / itemHeight;

                        string text = m_items[m_selected_index + m_scroll_index];
                        SelectedIndexChanged(this, new GosNIIAS.EventArgs<string>(text));
                        base.Text = text;
                        ControlState = ControlState.WaitingFeedback;
                    }
                    else
                        ControlState = ControlState.Normal;
                }
                else
                {
                    bounds = new Rectangle(m_drop_down_bounds.X + m_drop_down_bounds.Width - buttonWidth,
                                           m_drop_down_bounds.Y,
                                           buttonWidth,
                                           buttonHeight);
                    if (bounds.Contains(e.Location))
                    {
                        m_scroll_index -= 1;
                        m_scroll_index = Math.Max(0, m_scroll_index);
                        m_top_scroll_button_state = ButtonState.Pushed;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bounds = new Rectangle(m_drop_down_bounds.X + m_drop_down_bounds.Width - buttonWidth,
                                               m_drop_down_bounds.Y + m_drop_down_bounds.Height - buttonHeight,
                                               buttonWidth,
                                               buttonHeight);
                        if (bounds.Contains(e.Location))
                        {
                            m_scroll_index += 1;
                            m_scroll_index = Math.Min(m_items.Length - 10, m_scroll_index);
                            m_bottom_scroll_button_state = ButtonState.Pushed;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Visible && ControlState == MCDU.Drawing.ControlState.Edit)
        {
            if (m_drop_down_bounds.Contains(e.Location))
            {
                Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(m_drop_down_bounds.X,
                                                 m_drop_down_bounds.Y,
                                                 m_items.Length > 10 ? m_drop_down_bounds.Width - buttonWidth 
                                                                     : m_drop_down_bounds.Width,
                                                 m_drop_down_bounds.Height);
                if (bounds.Contains(e.Location) && m_items.Length > 0)
                {
                    int itemHeight = m_drop_down_bounds.Height / Math.Min(10, m_items.Length);
                    m_hightlight_index = (e.Location.Y - m_drop_down_bounds.Y) / itemHeight + m_scroll_index;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);

        m_top_scroll_button_state = ButtonState.Normal;
        m_bottom_scroll_button_state = ButtonState.Normal;
    }

    public override void DrawTopLayer(Graphics g)
    {
        if (Visible && ControlState == MCDU.Drawing.ControlState.Edit)
        {
            int itemHeight = GetItemHeight(g);

            Rectangle bounds = ClipRectangle;
            m_drop_down_bounds = new Rectangle(bounds.X,
                                               bounds.Y + bounds.Height,
                                               bounds.Width,
                                               itemHeight * Math.Max(1, Math.Min(10, m_items.Length)) + 2);
            g.FillRectangle(ForeBrush, m_drop_down_bounds);
            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(BackColor), new Rectangle(m_drop_down_bounds.X,
                                                              m_drop_down_bounds.Y,
                                                              m_drop_down_bounds.Width - 1,
                                                              m_drop_down_bounds.Height - 1));

            for (int index = 0; index < Math.Min(10, m_items.Length); index++)
            {
                Rectangle itemBounds = new Rectangle(bounds.X,
                                                     bounds.Y + bounds.Height + index * itemHeight,
                                                     m_items.Length > 10 ? bounds.Width - buttonWidth : bounds.Width,
                                                     itemHeight);
                if (m_hightlight_index == index + m_scroll_index)
                    g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Highlight), itemBounds);

                g.DrawString(m_items[index + m_scroll_index], Font, BackBrush, itemBounds, StringFormat);
            }

            if (m_items.Length > 10)
            {
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(m_drop_down_bounds.X + m_drop_down_bounds.Width - buttonWidth - 1,
                                                    m_drop_down_bounds.Y + 1,
                                                    buttonWidth,
                                                    itemHeight * 10);
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(SystemColors.ScrollBar), rectangle);

                rectangle = new Rectangle(m_drop_down_bounds.X + m_drop_down_bounds.Width - buttonWidth - 1,
                                          m_drop_down_bounds.Y + 1,
                                          buttonWidth,
                                          buttonHeight);
                ControlPaint.DrawScrollButton(g, rectangle, ScrollButton.Up, m_top_scroll_button_state);

                rectangle = new Rectangle(m_drop_down_bounds.X + m_drop_down_bounds.Width - buttonWidth - 1,
                                          m_drop_down_bounds.Y + 1 + itemHeight * 10 - buttonHeight,
                                          buttonWidth,
                                          buttonHeight);
                ControlPaint.DrawScrollButton(g, rectangle, ScrollButton.Down, m_bottom_scroll_button_state);

                int height = (int)((itemHeight * 10 - 2 * buttonHeight) * 10.0 / m_items.Length);

                int y = m_drop_down_bounds.Y + 1 + buttonHeight +
                        (int)((itemHeight * 10 - 2 * buttonHeight) * m_scroll_index / m_items.Length);

                rectangle = new Rectangle(m_drop_down_bounds.X + m_drop_down_bounds.Width - buttonWidth - 1,
                                          y,
                                          buttonWidth,
                                          height);
                ControlPaint.DrawButton(g, rectangle, ButtonState.Normal);
            }
        }
    }

    protected int GetItemHeight(Graphics g)
    {
        return (int)g.MeasureString(" ", Font).Height;
    }
}
```